# Mono Gtk.Dialog returning object as response

Tags: c#, mono, gtk, modal-dialog

I am trying to write a simple form application with mono Gtk# but am already stuck in the beginning  I create a Dialog form inherits from Gtk.Dialog. The dialog form for collection basic information and returning these information as an object to main window or trigger some event to main window so it can do what it suppose to do in this case bind the data a TreeView control (which is another story). These are what I have tried so far;

***Dialog code***

```
public partial class MyDialog : Gtk.Dialog
{
    public MyDialog ()
    {
        this.Build ();
    }

    protected void OnButtonOkClicked (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int portNumber = 0;
        iint.TryParse (spnPort.Text, out portNumber);

        var myObj = new MyObj ();
        myObj.Username = txtUsername.Text;
        myObj.Password = txtPassport.Text;

        // did not work as ParentWindow is a Gdk.Window
        //(this.ParentWindow as MainWindow).AddObj(myObj);

        //Also did not work because there is no response related method 
        //or property in the Dialog please read below code block this will make more sense
        //this.OnResponse(myObj);
    }


}
```

***MainWindow Code to call dialo***

```
protected void OnAddActionActivated (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyDialog s = new MyDialog();
    s.Run();
    s.Response += HandleResponse;
}

void HandleResponse (object o, ResponseArgs args)
{
    //as this event has args.Args and args.RetVal I thought one would do what I wanted 
    //maybe I am using them all wrong
}
```

I appreciate it if some one can explain what is Gdk.Window is and what it is doing under Gtk control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just store the object you want to return in your dialog object, and provide access to it using a property. Don't forget to check whether the user pressed the cancel button (if you have one), conveniently by examining the return value of `Run()`.

For an example see the [sample code for the stock FileChooserDialog](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=T%3aGtk.FileChooserDialog) in the official documentation.